# Get value for GridView templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this GridView

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPrices" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsPrices" AllowPaging="true"
    AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true" PageSize="20">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CapId" HeaderText="CapId" SortExpression="CapId" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Model") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Derivative") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Term" HeaderText="Term" SortExpression="Term" />
```

When I iterate through it to get values, the first one is fine, but the second one as it's a template field doesn't have a text property. How can I access it's value? I thought about FindControl but I don't know the id?

```
sb.Append(gvPrices.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text + ','); // has a value
sb.Append(gvPrices.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + ','); // doesn't have a value
```

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work for the Template Field, only the boundfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Label val =  (Label) gvPrices.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl('YourColumn');
```

If your Control in the Template field is Label, then convert it to that.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblVehicle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Manufacturer") + " " + Eval("Model") + " " +  Eval("Derivative") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I think something like above.

Comment: sb.Append(gvPrices.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl('Vehicle'). - there doesn't seem to be a Text property for FindControl?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That's correct. It doesn't have a Text property. You need to convert it.

Comment: You need to have all the text inside the Template Field in a Label's Text and then get that Label's ID in the 'YourColumn' and get its value as the Updated answer.

Comment: There is no control type to cast to - it's just <%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Model") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Derivative") %>

Comment: Use a Label for that text.

Comment: I tried to convert it to a label - <asp:Label ID="lblVehicle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Model") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Derivative") %>'></asp:Label> but I get - CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer by @Sorrel Vesper. It almost solved my problem. Just a little bit missing.

This is how I did it and it solved my problem:

First: Find the control by id and convert it to the corresponding control.
Second: Get the value of the control using the text property.

Ex:
- GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true" PageSize="20">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Product Name" 
        SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'>
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

- C#
TextBox txtPrice = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtPrice");
string price = (null == txtPrice) 
                     ? string.Empty 
                     : txtPrice.Text;
```

I hope it helps .